# Gambling Question

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, gambling

> **Exercise 4.21:** In a game you win \$10 with probability $\frac{1}{20}$ and lose \$1 with probability $\frac{19}{20}$. Approximate the probability that you lost less than \$100 after the first 200 games. How will this probability change after 300 games?

**Attempt**:

First, we show the winnings and losings together in a single variable. Define
\begin{equation*}
 W_n = 10S_n - (n - S_n)
\end{equation*}
where $W_n$ denotes the winnings after $n$ games and $S_n$ defines the number of wins in $n$ games. Thus,
\begin{equation*}
 P(W_n \geq 100) = P(11S_n - n> -100) = P\biggr(S_n > \frac{n - 100}{11}\biggr).
\end{equation*}
Now, we apply Central Limit Theorem in either case, with different values of $n$.

Let $n = 200$, then $S_n \sim Bin(200, \frac{1}{20})$. We thus wish for $S_n > \frac{100}{11}$. Moreover, $E[S_n] = 200 \cdot \frac{1}{20} = 10$ and Var$(S_n) = 200 \cdot \frac{1}{20} \cdot \frac{19}{20} = \frac{19}{2}.$ Thus, it follows from CLT with the continuity correction that
\begin{equation*}
 P\biggr(\frac{\frac{100}{11} - 10}{\sqrt{\frac{19}{2}}}< \frac{S_n - 10}{\sqrt{\frac{19}{2}}}\biggr) \approx 1 - \Phi(-0.457169) \approx 0.6772. 
\end{equation*}

**Now, the book gives a different answer for the first case of 200 games, that being of 0.5636. I wish to understand my mistake before moving on to the next case**

Intuitively this also makes sense as the condition of $S_n > \frac{100}{11}$ should be near the top of the bell curve of the normal distribution, as the expected value of 10 is close to $\frac{100}{11}$. However, for the life of my I can't spot the error in my calculation.

*(The other Math Stack Exchange question for this questions clarified nothing essentially for me, hence this post.)*

[Losing less than $100 in a game of chance.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494039/losing-less-than-100-in-a-game-of-chance)

Comment: I can't seem to spot an error in your reasoning, but my calculator says that the probability $N(\mu = 10, \sigma^2  = 19/2) > 100/11 \approx 0.616$.

Comment: For sake of completeness and traceability, please link to the other question(s) that you are referencing.

Comment: Thank you @heropup I updated the post.

Comment: Oh wow, you REALLY weren’t joking when you said that answer didn’t clarify anything!  Hahahaha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is the random number of wins in $n$ games, then $$X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 200, p = 0.05)$$ and the net win/loss random variable is $$W = 10X - (n-X) = 11X - n.$$  Thus $$\Pr[W > -100] = \Pr[11X - 200 > -100] = \Pr[X \ge 10].$$  This last expression is due to the fact that $X$ cannot take on fractional values.  Consequently, $$\Pr[X \ge 10] = 1 - \sum_{x=0}^{9} \binom{200}{x} (0.05)^x (0.95)^{200-x} \approx 0.54529\ldots.$$  This is the exact probability:  the only approximation here is in the rounding of the fraction to a decimal.

This also gives a key insight as to why your answer is incorrect:  just because you are using a normal approximation with continuity correction does not mean the outcomes for $W$ that you want to include in the desired probability can be outside the sample space for $W$.

For instance, if $U \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 500, p = 0.5)$, and I ask you for $\Pr[U < 225.999]$, you would first need to write $\Pr[U < 225.999] = \Pr[U \le 225]$, *then* you apply continuity correction to approximate it as $$\Pr\left[Z \le \frac{225.5 - 250}{5 \sqrt{5}}\right].$$  The same applies here; thus $$\Pr[W > -100] = \Pr[X \ge 10] \approx \Pr\left[\frac{X - 10}{\sqrt{9.5}} \ge \frac{9.5 - 10}{\sqrt{9.5}}\right] \approx \Pr[Z \ge -0.162221] \approx 0.564434.$$  Evidently, your text is rounding before completing the calculation, or it is using a standard normal table lookup without interpolation, since $\Pr[Z \ge -0.16] \approx 0.563559$.  In any case, the approximation $$\Pr[Z \ge -0.457169] \approx 0.676225$$ deviates far too much.

Comment: Ah, I see. The big misstep within my formation of the probability is assuming that it is possible to have fractional values for the number of wins when in reality it must be integer valued. Also, thank you for illuminating more insight with regards to the continuity correction.